# Rewrite rule that will get rid of the .php file extension in my URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, file-extension

I need a rewrite rule that will get rid of the .php file extension in my URL. I've tried the following. It doesn't work.

`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) the following code should work for Removing PHP Extensions.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: This code removes the entire extension, which in turn redirects me to the RewriteBase. I only need the .php removed.

Comment: I'm kind of new to stackoverflow. Can you tell me how to put my "code in question" into the proper format / text editor?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the .php extension completely , you can use the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1 redirect "/file.php" to "/file"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R]
#2 internally map "/file" back to "/file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```